# Get MousePosition in a Panel (when Mouse is over an other UIElement) to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Again I have a probably simple problem:

I am trying to get the MousePosition in my Scrollviewer:

```
CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.OriginalSource);
```

But the problem occures when my mouse is over an other UIElement - the source is the UIElement and not my Scrollviewer - "wrong" Position:

I would now that I could do a "`IsHitTestVisible="false"`" but I also need the HitTest of the Elements.

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <cmd:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MouseMoveCommand}"                   
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Canvas>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsToDraw}">
            <!-- A lot of stuff -->
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just set a `Name` for  `scrollViewer` and pass this name to `e.GetPosition()`?

Comment: i cannot access the Scrollviewer from my ViewModel?

Comment: This is pure UI interaction. This has nothing to do with UI - data cooperation. Consider using codebihind for such operations instead of viewmodel. Just in case: MVVM does not prohibit you from using codebehind)

Answer (score 1):

I think that before you do your assignment:

```
CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.OriginalSource);
```

you could do a check and quick exit when the sender is of a different type:

```
var scollViewer = e.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
if(scrollViewer == null) return; //short circuit 
CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(scrollViewer);
```

Also (with apologies for nagging), but it sounds like your property `CurrentMousePosition` is really for monitoring the `ScrollViewer`'s mouse position. If that is so, for clarity, it'd be better to name it `ScrollViewerMousePosition`